# Is there a way to install and use smart scopes in 13.04 ?

Tags: 13.04, smart, scopes

I would like to try the smart scopes feature because this would be the only reason for me to upgrade to saucy. is there a way to try the feature (the final version used in saucy) in ubuntu 13.04 ? And would I be able to uninstall it if I decide I don't like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install smart scopes from this ppa :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-unity/experimental-certified
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-experimental-certified
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then restart.

To uninstall simply run

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-unity/experimental-certified
```

If the purge segfaults you can try

```
sudo sed -i 's/^deb/#deb/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-unity-experimental-certified-raring.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-unity-experimental-certified
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-dee-1.0/raring gir1.2-unity-5.0/raring libdee-1.0-4/raring libdee-dev/raring libunity-common/raring libunity-core-6.0-5/raring libunity-dev/raring libunity-protocol-private0/raring libunity9/raring unity/raring unity-common/raring unity-lens-applications/raring unity-lens-files/raring unity-lens-music/raring unity-lens-photos/raring unity-lens-video/raring unity-lens-friends/raring unity-scope-musicstores/raring unity-scope-video-remote/raring unity-services/raring unity-scope-gdocs/raring unity-scope-gdrive/raring
```

Full info here : http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/how-to-install-unity-smart-scopes-in.html

Comment: well I tried it out and it seems to be the right way to do it but in my Computer it crashes Unity. Ubuntu will boot but neither launcher or panel will show. I could still open a terminal via shortcut to revert the changes but apparently I have to upgrade to 13.10 to get the feature working.